# Is it USA , UK? or UK, USA

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

To explain in Global Market about the USA and Uk, in the sentence which word should I write first Between USA and UK, is it USA, UK? or Uk, USA?

Comment: Is there a rule in your native language.  If you were writing in you native language, which would you have to write first?

Comment: ***U**nited **K**ingdom*. Both words are ***always*** capitalised when used as a pair to refer to the "nation state" of Great Britain.

Comment: Apparently, [we Brits just win the "precedence" contest](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+USA+and+the+UK%2Cthe+UK+and+the+USA&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) - sequence ***the UK and the USA*** is slightly more common than ***the USA and the UK***.

Comment: @Faruk Ahmed Rana, You choose the first one as you want or need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to you.  This is a list of two country names. There is no rule for the ordering of nouns in lists. They are listed in the order that the author chooses to list them.

Comment: thanks for your reply, for me it's hard to choose. which is most common in use?

Comment: Heads is UK, USA,  tails is  USA, UK  https://justflipacoin.com/

Comment: I got it, Thanks again! :) I'm going to Write USA, Uk. It's the sequence of most people write! btw the flip coin was mostly showed tails! ;)

Comment: @FarukAhmedRana But note that it's the UK, not the Uk.